# Bachelors in computer science and wanting a masters?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, engineering

I graduated with a 2.98gpa in computer science with a minor in math. I am currently employed as a software engineer and I am wanting to go back to school for a masters degree. I would really like to Perdue a professional engineering masters and take the PE(professional engineering exam) after I graduate.
 Is it even possible to go from a computer science bachelors degree to a masters program in systems engineering or computer engineering?  I am currently looking at the university of Alabama in Huntsville. I want a masters degree, but I don't specifically care to stick with computer science. I am wanting to broaden my horizons and prepare myself for a role in management in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is that your grades are only so-so. The good news is that you found a job in your field. Your job may become your best "reference."

To take full advantage of that, I wouldn't think about going back to school immediately, but after three years on the job (the optimal time). Then you will have "work experience" and "maturity" to offer, over then newly graduated students with higher GPAs, having put some distance between your application and your lackluster academic career.

To further strengthen your credentials, you might take one course a semester at university as a "special student, five or six in total, in your relevant area of study.

Comment: Good advice! Here we are 2 years later and I graduate with my master's degree in computer science from a state school tomorrow!

Comment: @TravisTubbs: Congratulations. I'm glad to hear my advice helped.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be up to the school.  Contact the institution(s) you are interested in and ask.  Some schools will have stronger or weaker requirements, some may require you to take additional classes, some wont.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a lot out of university advisement, but the most important thing is to figure out what degree program fits your interests.  Read the programs of study and course descriptions carefully.

If the program you are interested in has some prerequisites that you haven't taken, then consider working your way through those as an unmatriculated student, one course at a time, while you are still employed, before applying to grad school.  When you are ready to apply, you can submit a transcript showing these individual courses, to supplement your Bachelor's transcript.